# Exterior door to deck is 24" but only have 27.5" workable space. Doable?

Tags: doors, framing

I'm designing a second story deck and the wall that will provide access is only 27.5" wide. I'd like to put in a 24" x 80" exterior door there. It's up against the corner of the house on one side (all 2x4 beams) and a wall on the other side. Everything will be new construction so I can tinker how the framing will be done. It's in California and I will be getting permits.

[image]

[image]

Comment: To add pictures, just [edit] your question, the click the "sun & mountain" icon above the text edit box and follow the instructions. Or, simply drag the picture(s) into the text edit box and it will happen automatically.

Answer (score 1):

[image]The minimum rough opening for a 24 x 80 door is 25.75" x 81.5".

That's the rough opening that is the result of the proper framing.

If you have enough room to frame the corners and have king and jack studs for the opening then you are ok.  If you're telling us the entire floor space from the outside of the corner to the wall is 27.5 inches, then you do not have enough space to properly install an exterior door.

With the diagram and new info. If you have concrete block exterior walls, you can reduce the dimensions by 1" (red marks) off the reveals and you have the 26" needed for your door.

If the walls are stick framing, make the 2 red marked studs the jacks. That gives you 25.5" of rough opening. You should be able to squeeze a door in there as it is "rough" framing.  Moving the washer/dryer closet wall 1/2" will solve the problem too.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to add a screen shot, but haven't figured that out. The dimension from the inside corner to the wall on the other side is 27.5". The walls will be 2x4, so the dimension to the outside of that corner will add 5.5" (because it's an exterior wall) so 33".

Comment: If you figure that you need just a jack stud on each side and have that fit to the inside of the exterior wall you still need 28.5 inches.  I'm not sure how to squeeze out another inch without seeing what you actually have.  ( you can use the sun and moon box above your question to add a pic.)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not seeing a sun and moon above my question. Maybe because I'm new, I'm not yet allowed to post pictures?

Comment: my bad    mountains and moon... square

Comment: Can you attach of picture of what you're talking about? lol. I don't see anything remotely like that.

Comment: Ok, I was able to add another inch by moving the wall on the other side of the corner up an inch. Now I have 28.5". That will be sufficient? Typically I know you need 3" on either side of a door.

Comment: Don't you need room for both a jack stud and a king stud here (hence the 3" per side), in addition to the door jamb thickness?

Comment: @LennyB,  to add a pic , click on the EDIT tab.  above the body of your post are characters . From the left there is a B an I for italics 2 rings to add a link , "", {}, and then a square with what looks like mountains and a moon on a black background.  Click that to add a pic.

Comment: Ok, picture should be there.

Comment: A diagram is there. I'm still confused as to where you want a door.  I was expecting a picture of the area.

Comment: It's new construction, so there is nothing but a diagram. In the center of the picture there is a 2' exterior door that leads from a spiral staircase landing to a balcony. It shows 2.25" gaps on either side of the door. The wall of the spiral staircase area ends at the door and then there is a railing for the balcony. On the opposite side of that door is a wall that is the back of the washer/dryer closet.

Comment: I added a second, more zoomed in, picture.

Comment: Well if this hasn't been built yet, go back to the draftsman or Architect and tell them you want a 2/0  (24") door there. They should be able to adjust accordingly.

Comment: That's me. And there is a 24" door there, but in a 28.5" space, which I'm trying to determine if that will be doable. I don't want to have to make any other adjustments if it can be built this way.

Comment: Are the exterior walls concrete block?  If not what are the walls made of?  If you have a block opening you only need room for your door and frame and shimming for adjustments and that is 25.75 "  The door frame is anchored to the block with a lintel above.  So no need for king or jack studs.

Comment: Edited my answer to include your pic and new info.

Comment: It's all 2x4 wood framing

Comment: You can probably get by without dedicated king studs, as the framing for the adjacent walls should serve that purpose.  You would only need the jack studs for the header.  If you're using a pre-hung door, you might be able to do it—they have a 26" rough opening.  Looks like you could have that.

Comment: As Huesmann 53 pointed out, the king studs can be part of the other walls, so you can do this.  I edited my answer again to reflect stick framing options.

Comment: Thanks guys for all your help!